# Angular 2 : dynamically import files in component from environment variable

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am trying to import customized files based on chosen environment. I created an environment file and added a path variable to it.

environment.test.ts

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    file_path: '../../folder/file.ts'
};
```

component.ts

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

Now, how do I import file from file_path in this component?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import { MyFile } from 'MyFile';

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  myFile: MyFile
};
```

And switch the files in environment.ts and environment.prod.ts

Comment: I have different environments like test, dev, prod. And for every environment I want to use different myFile path. How can I do that?

Comment: That's another tricky problem, and there are several issues on GitHub for supporting multiple environments. I've done a workaround by replacing placeholders via build server. I've added placeholders in evironment.prod.ts like #{myVar}# and replace them after bundling...not sexy, but working